# Clear content from text file in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, overwrite

I am new to iOS and Objective C and I am trying to create my first app.

I have a small text file with a few lines of data and at some point, I must clear all the data from that file before adding new lines.

I search for a while but I wasn't able to find anything. I'm pretty sure it must be a way but I could find it.

I could delete the file and recreate it before adding but I don't think it's the right approach.

I also tried overwriting the content like here: 
[Overwriting current contents in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560702/overwriting-current-contents-in-file)

but it didn't seam to work (it adds the data at the beginning of the file) and I cannot seam to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't need the previous data, overwriting the file seems perfectly appropriate. If you are only saving a little bit of data though you might want to take a look at `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: and if you save a big amount of data, you should take a look at      

    CoreData

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did take a look at NSUserDefaults but my intention is to be able to share this file via mail and to upload it to a server for further use so going this was seamed the best choice at the time.

Comment: If you want to share the file, just overwrite it if you don't care about previous data. That will probably be easier/faster than having to edit the file.

Comment: Thanks cabellicar. It is indeed easier since I already have methods for creating and adding data to file. I just need to call them. I'll do this instead. @ Bogdan Somlea - I'll take a look. I'll be needing it soon. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You don't need to "clear" a file to overwrite it. Simply write the new version of the file, and the old data will be gone, for all intents and purposes.  You have to make an extra effort to "append" to a file to keep it from being overwritten when you write more to it.

Comment: Thanks HotLicks (lol). I simply call the create methodto overwrite it. For appending I use something like this:                                                                               NSFileHandle *fileHandler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:channelsPath];

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 NSArray *allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [allPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathForUrFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.txt"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:pathForUrFile contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil];
```

in this way you can set the file content to `nil`